# The SHA1 of "App signing certificate" and "Upload certificate" each belong to two different keystores. How is this possible?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, android-app-bundle

For a couple of days, I've been trying to upload the aab of an existing app. We have never tried aab before, so this was a fresh attempt. I encountered an error saying "Your android app bundle is signed with the wrong key", which indicated a mismatch of SHA1. So I cleaned the project, rebuilt, invalidated cache (because why not) and tried again - the error persisted. Although, uploading regular APKs work fine with this keystore.

Out of curiosity, I tried building the signed aab with another keystore in our project directory (one that no one used) and to my surprise, this newly signed aab was accepted. This seemed impossible, and I found the SHA1 of "App signing certificate" belongs to one keystore, while the "Upload certificate" belongs to another keystore.

I don't understand how is this possible. We have multiple people access the dev console. Even if it's a human error, how was the upload certificate from the wrong keystore accepted? How can I have this fixed so that I can upload the aab with the actual keystore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you (or someone in your team) enrolled your app in *App Signing by Play*, you must have created this second keystore to create the **upload key** and uploaded the certificate to Google Play (by simply following the given instructions).

The **upload key** is the one that should be used to sign the future APKs and App Bundles.

The reason that your APKs can still be uploaded with your original **app signing key** even after creating this upload key is that Play wanted to allow for this transition time where you're just testing the App Bundle in some testing track but don't want your current APK release process be affected in the meantime, so they'll still accept the APKs to be uploaded with the app signing key.

Ideally, you should now put the keystore containing your app signing key in a safe location with restricted ACLs (since having it compromised can have devastating consequences, i.e. have to migrate all your users to a new app) and only use the keystore containing your upload key (which, if compromised, can be reset).

For some explanation about upload keys and app signing keys, I recommend reading the documentation here:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en-US

Comment: So this means, the new keystore that was used to enrol into _App Signing by Play_ is now the new keystore that we should care about for future aab releases. And for APKs, we'll have to use the old keystore. Have I understood this correctly?

Comment: The new keystore should be used for both your APKs and AABs. You *can* choose to use the old keystore for uploading APK if that's somehow more convenient for you, but as I said, I'd recommend to stop using it altogether and keep it in place secure.